# выбор данных из связующей таблицы для many-to-many с помощью Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Я делаю чат с пользователями, у меня в БД есть many-to-many между сущностью `User` и сущностью `Chat` (соответственно таблицы `user, chat, chat_user`)
Я пытаюсь написать запрос с помощью Doctrine, который выбирает все чаты в которых состоит user + всех пользователей из этих чатов.

На чистом SQL составил такой запрос:

```
FROM chat c
         INNER JOIN chat_user cu ON c.id = cu.chat_id
         INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = cu.user_id
WHERE c.id IN (SELECT chat_id
               FROM chat_user
               WHERE user_id = <userId>)
```

Мне непонятно как перегнать в доктрину подзапрос `SELECT chat_id FROM chat_user WHERE user_id = <userId>`, т. е. как выбрать именно из промежуточной таблицы, если я не делал отдельную сущность для нее.

Вот такой код

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('ch')
            ->innerJoin('ch.users', 'us')
            ->andWhere('us.id = :idUser')
            ->setParameter('idUser', $idUser)
            ->select('ch.id')
            ->getQuery()
            ;
```

вернет то же самое, что и подзапрос с выбором из chat_user, но этот код в дальнейшем будет преобразован в запрос с join, так что это не подходит.
Кроме того, данные необходимо выбирать одним запросом во избежание проблемы n + 1.

И второй вопрос: можно ли каким-то образом в данном случае с помощью Doctrine вообще без подзапроса обойтись?

Answer (score 0):

Если отдельная сущность под таблицу сделана то, можно посмотреть в сторону ExpressionBuilder
[Официальная документация доктрины](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/1.6/expression-builder.html)
[Разбор подобного запроса на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637506/doing-a-where-in-subquery-in-doctrine-2)

Если же сущности как таковой заведено не было, то скорее всего DQL не сможет корректно отработать с таким запросом. Я бы в таком случае попробовал RawSQL

[Документация](https://github.com/knpuniversity/doctrine-queries/blob/master/knpu/raw-sql-queries.md)

Однако, сразу скажу что не призываю так делать, я считаю наиболее правильным для вас путем завести таки недостающую сущность и использовать ExpressionBuilder

Comment: Я как раз использовал RawSQL ранее, а сейчас задался вопросом можно ли это сделать данную задачу с помощью QueryBuilder. Разве не будет избыточным заводить сущность ради выполнения одного запроса?

Comment: Не совсем так, сейчас вам может казаться что сущность лишняя, но в дальнейшем вам она пригодится при росте проекта. Кроме того, чем больше вы будете пользовать RAW запросы без сущности, тем сложнее Вам будет рефакторить код в дальнейшем.

Comment: Продолжение моего вопроса: создал отдельную сущность ```ChatUser``` и попытался выбрать ```chat_id``` в зависимости в зависимости от ```user_id```таким образом: ```$subQuery = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->getRepository(ChatUser::class)
            ->createQueryBuilder('chus')
            ->select('chus.chat')
            ->andWhere('chus.user = :idUser')
            ->setParameter('idUser', $idUser)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
```

Comment: В результате получил ошибку получил ошибку ```[Semantical Error] line 0, col 12 near 'chat FROM App\Entity\ChatUser': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression. ``` Причина в том, что поле чат было помечено как joinColumn. Если дописать аннотацию что это просто column, то select выше работает, однако как join column поле чат уже не воспринимается. Получается что работать со связующими таблицами через QueryBuilder все-таки не получится?

Comment: А что Вам выдаст в ответе этот же запрос если добавить в select('identity(chus.chat)')